# Getting Values Out of XLRD in Python

Tags: python, xlrd

Is there any way to get strings out of excel spreadsheets with XLRD? I'm handling data with Electricity Meters, and the ID number of the meters keeps being returned out as a float, with a ".0" on the end. It has forced me to a halt, so if anyone has any ideas, that would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code and data example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i have excel data as shown below 
[electrical.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIbUC.png)

The code which i can write to check if there is any float data type present. If it is present, then convert to string.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('electrical.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = []
for row in range(0, sheet.nrows):
    l = []
    for column in range(0, sheet.ncols):
        val = sheet.cell(row, column).value
        if isinstance(val,float):
            l.append(int(val))
        else:
            l.append(val)

    data.append(l)

print(data) # [['Meter ID', 'value'], ['id101', '1'], ['id102', '2'], ['id103', '3']]
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it still has the pesky ".0" at the end of the string for some reason

Comment: Updated code, now you can have output like.
# [['Meter ID', 'value'], ['id101', '1'], ['id102', '2'], ['id103', '3']]